# Concatenating multiple blobs produces corrupt media file

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, web-mediarecorder

I have a [media recorder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder) that I instantiate like so:

```
const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, {
  mimeType: 'video/x-matroska;codecs=h264',
  videoBitsPerSecond: 2500000,
  audioBitsPerSecond: 128000,
});

mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (e) => {
  const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(e.data);
  try {
    const hyperlink = document.createElement('a');
    hyperlink.href = blobUrl;
    hyperlink.target = '_blank';
    hyperlink.download = 'some_file_name_' + Date.now();

    const evt = new MouseEvent('click', {
      view: globalThis.window,
      bubbles: true,
      cancelable: true
    });
    hyperlink.dispatchEvent(evt);
  } finally {
    URL.revokeObjectURL(blobUrl);
  }
};

mediaRecorder.start(5000);
```

This code leaves me with a number of small files in my Downloads folder. I want to concatenate them together, which I did using Node's `appendFile` API. The issue is that the video file doesn't play correctly after the first segment. Does anyone have any advice on debugging this?

Comment: _"This code leaves me with a number of small files in my Downloads folder. I want to concatenate them together"_ - So why are you using `ondataavailable` then _"which is periodically triggered"_? Check the example on the page you've linked in your question which shows how to store a complete recording instead of chunks.

Comment: @Andreas because it's important that the recording be saved periodically in event of an unexpected shutdown.

Comment: Then, once again, check the link in your question. _`ondataavailable`: ...which is periodically triggered (or **when the entire media has been recorded**, if `timeslice` wasn't specified)"_. Either use the "last" `ondataavailable` or simply add a `onstop` handler.

Comment: @Andreas thanks for taking the time to help. The timeslice parameter was provided and I am regularly getting data out of the media recorder. The issue is that combining the data together on disk fails whereas it succeeds when done in memory.

Comment: There's nothing to combine if you just store the complete recording in the `onstop` event

Comment: @Andreas sorry for not being more clear. I am making a very long recording, and it's not feasible to store the entire thing in memory. Additionally, if Chrome dies mid-way through the recording, I would like to be able to recover the recording.

Comment: @Andreas I figured out the issue, if you're curious

Answer (score 0):

There were two issues.

The first issue was that the blob download needed the appropriate type, which was `application/octet-stream`. The way I achieved this was:

```
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = (_) => {
      const result = reader.result as ArrayBuffer;
      const blob = new Blob([result], { type: 'application/octet-stream' });
      const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      // Download the blob
    }
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(e.data);
```

The second issue is that default encoding for readFile is null, which is good. But the default encoding for appendFile is `utf8`, which is bad.

This can be fixed with `promisify(appendFile)(filename, data, { encoding: 'binary' });`